Custom Quantitative Finance design and logo - Information gathering
Congratulations, Quantitative Finance community! We’re going to be creating a custom site design for you that we hope will represent your subject and we want you all to really love it. You’ve been waiting almost 5 years and we really want to do this well. To facilitate this, we’re reaching out now to ask you for what you’d really love to see in the design and logo.
I’m Piper, Director of Product Design for our Community Products org. I’ll be working closely with our Community Managers to deliver a theme that truly represents who you are as a community. I have absolutely no knowledge of quantitative finance, so I’ll be depending heavily on you all to help me understand what makes this Stack Exchange unique and interesting.
A quick history lesson about site theming
Originally, site designs were part of the site graduation process. When a site left beta, they'd get their design. But, at the time we only had one designer who was working on designs and the designs were very specialized and often involved a lot of custom illustrations. We got into a situation where several sites were in queue for graduation but the designer didn't have the bandwidth to actually create the designs.
Before she worked here, Catija asked the question Can Beta sites slated for graduation get full-site abilities without site design upgrade? on MSE. This kicked off several discussions within the CM team of the time and community members and the eventual decision was to implement "Design-independent graduation" in September 2015. This meant that many sites were finally able to leave beta without waiting on a design - including this one!
At that time we also had much more strict guidelines for when a site could graduate - they had to consistently get 10 new questions per day. This level of volume made graduation impossible or very unlikely for many sites - meaning many would stay in beta forever. As such, the CM team considered another request - Let's break up with "Graduation" and remove a bunch of "Beta" labels - and that's what eventually happened, too. In 2019, we removed the beta label from 29 sites and another 59 in December 2021.
We've also gone through several design systems changes, including launching Stacks version 1.0, which make creating and building in designs much simpler for both our design team and the developers. In fact, we showed off how flexible it could be in our April Fools' prank this year, "Filters for Stack Overflow", where I personally created the Frisa Lank theme.
What to expect
Over the next few weeks, we'll be communicating with you about your site design, so please help us out as much as you can. While we may not be experts in Quantitative Finance, we know that you are and that you have great ideas about what you want this site to look like - so share them with us! You've got a week now to pool up your thoughts in answers to this question, at which point I'll start working on this site.
I'll spend some time working on a design based on your guidance, and we'll be back when it's ready to show you what the design and logo look like. At that point, you will have a week to make suggestions for adjustments to the design. Our hope is that there will be little that needs adjusting but, due to the size of our backlog, we can't allow more than one phase of feedback, so any changes will need to be recommended at this point.
We'll then consider the changes proposed and make any adjustments that we feel are beneficial. Changes that are too big or are out of scope likely won't be possible, but we'll make sure to explain why we opted against making a change should that happen. Please understand that design is often a subjective thing and we may end up with community members differing in their opinions, so we'll be taking that into account when deciding. Decisions about the final design will be made by the design team and CMs with the concerns of the community taken into account.
Also, it's worth keeping in mind that the goal of these designs is to make something topical, unique, and attractive, but we'll be designing within the scope of our newer site theming. We'll be able to create a logo, background colors, and textures in addition to your logo - but please don't expect illustrations like what you may have seen on some of the older site designs.
Process
Over the next month or so, we’ll be going through a few steps to get your site design up and running. This post is the first of those steps. I’ll also be using this post to track the phases in the table below.




Step
Status




Information Gathering
complete


Design V1
complete


V1 Feedback
complete


Design adjustments (if needed)
complete


Developer cleanup and shipping of final design
complete



What we need from you
As I've mentioned already, we need some inspiration from you so that we can get started on this design and create something you'll really be proud of. So far, I couldn't find any discussions about logos and site designs here on Meta – but if I've missed them, feel free to reference them if there are ideas you like already – or give us new ones! We're really looking for design ideas, rather than needing you to design anything for us.
When you're answering this question, think about:

What symbols or images are important to the subject of this site?

Especially things that speak to insiders that we might not find on our own


Are there any colors that are tied to your subject?
What tone/mood/feeling would you like your theme to emit? While this is subjective, it helps to set some design guardrails. So, when answering with your thoughts, some good axes to mention are where the theme might sit inside these spectra

From fun to serious
From classic to modern
From simple to complex


How could a good logo represent your subject?
What are things to avoid?

If you have any questions, let me know! We're really looking forward to hearing from you and getting your site design underway.

Perhaps a visualisation of the volatility smirk/surface?

@Kevin: Given that Piper is not familiar with quantitative finance, you may want to include a link and/or image of what you're referring to (ideally, you should post an answer containing this info).

I think it looks very good.

Update: Your new site design is live!

Looks great!!! Thank you very much!!!

I might be out of line with others, but I think an equation or a formula would not look good as a small logo. A graph (like the option pay-off) might be a better choice.
However, I wouldn't be afraid to go with the "cliche" image of finance, along the lines of the below:


I would definitely include the Black-Scholes equation, which is one of the most famous and relevant ones

as for the colors I personally would like a blue-ish theme

A simple graph like this might make a good logo (but without any words or symbols)


I would keep the Black-Scholes equation as apocalypsis mentions above as well as the last equation (the fundamental asset pricing formula).
I just feel that is unfortunate that the coins cover the equations. Can we shift the coins to the right on the top banner?

Colourwise: green for up and red for down is very common in Finance.
I think serious but simple would fit best.
Regarding Kevin’s comment, maybe you can take inspiration from this book cover:
http://emanuelderman.com/volatility-smile/
